# Replace value in a column with 'blank' if it matches the value in another column

Tags: r, match, na

I have a following data set as a data frame within R

```
article_number   1st_cutoff_date   2nd_cutoff_date

abc                12/01/2019       01/14/2020

def                02/10/2020       02/10/2020
```

What I want to do is in cases where 1st_cutoff_date == 2nd_cutoff_date, then replace 2nd_cutoff date with blank value " ".  So in the second case 'def' then 2nd_cutoff_date would be blank " "

the data frame is of factors and there are NA's - I have converted to character and tried the following:

```
AAR_FTW_Final_w_LL[AAR_FTW_Final_w_LL$`1st_Booking_Deadline` == AAR_FTW_Final_w_LL$`2nd_Booking_Deadline`, c("2nd_Booking_Deadline")] <- " "
```

&

```
ind<- AAR_FTW_Final_w_LL$`1st_Booking_Deadline` == AAR_FTW_Final_w_LL[`2nd_Booking_Deadlilne`]
AAR_FTW_Final_w_LL[ind, c("2nd_Booking_Deadline")] <- " "
```

Both return the error:

```
Error in AAR_FTW_Final_w_LL$`1st_Booking_Deadline` : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I have tried replacing the $ with [] but then I get the error that one of the columns is missing.  Is there any easier way to do to this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert from factors to characters :

```
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)
```

Then use `replace`

```
transform(df, `2nd_cutoff_date` = replace(`2nd_cutoff_date`, 
                            `1st_cutoff_date` == `2nd_cutoff_date`, ''))

#  article_number X1st_cutoff_date X2nd_cutoff_date
#1            abc       12/01/2019       01/14/2020
#2            def       02/10/2020
```

It adds `X` to the column name since it is not a standard in R to have columns starting with a number.

---

Another approach after you convert the data to characters would be

```
df$`2nd_cutoff_date`[df$`1st_cutoff_date` == df$`2nd_cutoff_date`] <- ""
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(article_number = structure(1:2, .Label = c("abc", 
"def"), class = "factor"), `1st_cutoff_date` = structure(2:1, 
.Label = c("02/10/2020", "12/01/2019"), class = "factor"), 
`2nd_cutoff_date` = structure(1:2, .Label = c("01/14/2020", 
"02/10/2020"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Why the `\`` backticks? "1st_cutoff_date" should be a valid name.

Comment: I am relatively new to R it seems to add them automatically but I do keep getting an error when trying the above: Error in replace(`2nd_Booking_Deadline`, `1st_Booking_Deadline` == `2nd_Booking_Deadline`,  : 
  object '2nd_Booking_Deadline' not found

Comment: its like it doesn't recognize - if I remove the back ticks then the numerical part starts being treated like a number in R - i.e. its highlighted differently

Comment: @thelatemail It is not for me. Doesn't work when I remove the backticks.

Comment: @XCCH004 Are you sure you are using the correct column name? Do you have `\`2nd_Booking_Deadline\`` or `\`2nd_cutoff_date\`` ?

Comment: my apologies - the columns are 1st_Booking_Deadline and 2nd_Booking_Deadline but the results are the same either way - sorry for the confusion

Comment: I was reading the wrong part of the code

Comment: @RonakShah - ahhh.... i wasn't thinking - it can't start with a number.

Comment: @XCCH004 Are you using the correct dataframe name ? Step 1) `AAR_FTW_Final_w_LL[] <- lapply(AAR_FTW_Final_w_LL, as.character)` Step 2) `AAR_FTW_Final_w_LL$\`2nd_Booking_Deadline\`[AAR_FTW_Final_w_LL $\`1st_Booking_Deadline\` == AAR_FTW_Final_w_LL $\`2nd_Booking_Deadline\`] <- ""` What does it return to you ?

Comment: that worked - sorry for the confusion...thank you so much - one question what does the [] do in the first step?

Comment: @XCCH004 `lapply` returns a list. Using `[]` maintains it's dimensions so `AAR_FTW_Final_w_LL` would still remain as dataframe.

Comment: excellent knowledge - thanks a ton